# How to solve below chart problems with `MPChartAndroid`?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I have 3 issue related to `MPChartAndroid`.

How to make chart to see selected values.
1. Add space to the left of LeftAxis and to the right of rightAxis to fully see the values.
2. how to make first and last chart value to fully see the values.
3. Add space under xAxis to see the cut text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome issue with cutoff x-Axis label, you need to set some extra space on bottom of your chart view. 
`mLineChart.setExtraOffsets(left,top,right,bottom);` try code below

```
mLineChart.setExtraOffsets(0,0,0,10);
```

For overcome issue with overlapping value on axis line you need to set some spacing (start position of lines) on x-Axis, try code below

```
xAxis.setSpaceMax(0.01f);
xAxis.setSpaceMin(0.01f);
```

also try `xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);`

Comment: Thanks, overlapping problem is because I have the same numbers for yAxis is it possible to show point value under the point for some sets? or give a bit vertical space between them by force.